# How to synchronize code based on boolean value?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, atomic, synchronized

I have this code:

```
    private volatile boolean immortal;
    private Object lock = new Object();
    
    public void set(boolean immortal) {
        this.immortal = immortal;
    }

    public void kill() {
       // .... contains some other code. 
       synchronized(lock) {
            if (!immortal) {
               for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
                   runnableList.add(POISON_PILL);
               }
            }
       }
    }
```

My use case is that I would like the if statement in the `kill` method to run to completion before `immortal` value is changed. Is there a better way of doing this without locking on an object?

I mean what is the best way to synchronize a block only if the value of a boolean variable is false and not allow the boolean value to be changed till it runs to completion? Can I achieve this using `AtomicBoolean`?

Comment: "Not allow the boolean value to be changed till it runs to completion" - is your current implementation supposed to achieve this? From what I can tell nothing stops other threads from changing `immortal` during execution of the synchronized block.

Answer (score 3):

A neat way to do this could be to declare your `runnableList` as a synchronized list:

```
// where T is whatever type it needs to be
List<T> runnableList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Then you could add to it without explicit synchronization:

```
if (!immortal) {
  runnableList.addAll(Collections.nCopies(numThreads, POISON_PILL));
}
```

This works because a single call to `addAll` is atomic.

This isn't doing it *without* synchronization, though, it's just internal to the list.

---

With this said, it's hard to recommend a "better" solution because it's not clear what the requirements are. Synchronization (etc) is used to preserve the invariants of your object when operated on by multiple threads.

For example, *why* do you need `immortal` to remain unchanged while you add things to `runnableList`? How else do you access `immortal` and `runnableList`? etc

Answer (score 1):

Use two locks:

```
private boolean immortal;
private final Object killMonitor = new Object();
private final Object flagMonitor = new Object();

public void set(boolean immortal) {
    synchronized (flagMonitor) {
        this.immortal = immortal;
    }
}

public void kill() {
    // ...
    synchronized (flagMonitor) {
        if (!immortal) {
            synchronized (killMonitor) {
                runnableList.addAll(Collections.nCopies(numThreads, POISON_PILL));
            }
        }
    }
}
```